# Error converting data type varchar to numeric VB.Net(Windows Service)?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a windows service (VB.NET) to copy data from a SQL table to another SQL table (in a different database & server). When I start the service it just give me this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

PS : I'm surprised with this error since I don't see any varchar data type in my source table.

[Source Table(NOR_LABOR) columns and data types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GDK2.png)
Sample Source Table : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd4fb/1

[Destination Table(ALL_LABOR_DETAILS) columns and data types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/921bE.png)
Sample Destination Table : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7eb72/1

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class DataCollector

    Dim con1, con2 As New SqlConnection
    Dim timer1 As Timers.Timer
    Dim p_oConn As New Wisys.AllSystem.ConnectionInfo
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

        con1 = New SqlConnection("Data Source=NORMAC-CTMS\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Normac Data;Integrated Security=true")

        Try
            con1.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            FileIO.WriteLog(ex.Message)
        End Try

        con2 = New SqlConnection("Data Source=STLEDGSQL01;Database=MES_DEV;Integrated Security=true")

        Try
            con2.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            FileIO.WriteLog(ex.Message)
        End Try

        timer1 = New Timers.Timer()
        timer1.Interval = 5000
        AddHandler timer1.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
        timer1.Enabled = True
        FileIO.WriteLog("Service has started")

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        timer1.Enabled = False
        FileIO.WriteLog("Service has stopped")
        con1.Close()
        con2.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnTimedEvent(obj As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim cmd1, cmd2, cmd3 As SqlCommand

        'Connecting the Normac Data table
        Dim da1 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select ID, RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(department), RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator), RTRIM(total_labor_hours), RTRIM(feet_produced), RTRIM(item_no), RTRIM(posted), RTRIM(lot_no), RTRIM(default_bin) from NOR_LABOR where ID > 46006 order by ID", con1)
        Dim cb1 As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da1)
        Dim dt1 As DataTable = New DataTable()
        da1.Fill(dt1)

        Dim i As Integer

        'Inserting Normac Data  into ALL_LABOR_DETAILS table
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt1.Rows
            Try
                cmd1 = New SqlCommand("Insert into ALL_LABOR_DETAILS values('" & dr(0) & "','" & dr(1) & "','" & dr(2) & "','" & dr(3) & "','" & dr(4) & "','" & dr(5) & "','" & dr(6) & "','" & dr(7) & "','" & dr(8) & "','" & dr(9) & "','" & dr(10) & "','','','','','" & dr(11) & "','" & dr(12) & "','','','','','','','')", con2)
                i = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                FileIO.WriteLog("Most Recent Normac ID " & mostRecentNormacID)
            Catch ex As Exception
                FileIO.WriteLog(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next
        da1.Update(dt1)
        cmd1.Dispose()
        dt1.Dispose()
        da1.Dispose()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please remove the VB6 tag from this posting as it clearly doesn't apply to this code.

Comment: Heap of questions.  First question.  Would be incredibly helpful to know exactly where  the exception is occurring.  I would suggest at least for development do this as a console app, much easier than attaching debuggers to services.

Comment: I'm sorry sir didn't notice that, it's just a big project which contains VB6 too and this is a part of it which doesn't. Just removed VB6 tag.

Comment: Next question, why all the string concatenations.  Generally if there are sql syntax problems, easily solved by looking at the generated sql.  Even better use parameters

Comment: Next question.  Why trim everything in your initial query.  If you want variable length strings. use either varchar or nvarchar

Comment: This looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Is ID varchar in the source NOR_LABOR table?  Most likely you invalid string data in that field.  When you compare it to an integer, WHERE ID > 46006, you are implicitly converting the ID to a integer field.  If any data in that table cannot be translated into an int, you'll receive the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, including fixing a few poor practices, *especially the SQL injection issue!* Don't forget to set the correct types and lengths for your actual database table in the appropriate place in this code (there's a comment pointing it out).

```vb
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class DataCollector

    Dim conString1 As String = "Data Source=NORMAC-CTMS\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Normac Data;Integrated Security=true"
    Dim conString2 As String = "Data Source=STLEDGSQL01;Database=MES_DEV;Integrated Security=true"
    Dim timer1 As Timers.Timer

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

        timer1 = New Timers.Timer()
        timer1.Interval = 5000
        AddHandler timer1.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
        timer1.Enabled = True
        FileIO.WriteLog("Service has started")

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        timer1.Enabled = False
        FileIO.WriteLog("Service has stopped")
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnTimedEvent(obj As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim sql1 As String = "
SELECT ID, RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(department),
    RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator),
    RTRIM(total_labor_hours), RTRIM(feet_produced), RTRIM(item_no),
    RTRIM(posted), RTRIM(lot_no), RTRIM(default_bin) 
FROM NOR_LABOR 
WHERE ID > 46006
ORDER BY ID ;
"

        Dim sql2 As String = "
INSERT INTO ALL_LABOR_DETAILS 
VALUES 
(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12);
"

        Dim dt As new DataTable

        Try
            Using cn  As New SqlConnection(conString1), _
                  cmd As New SqlCommand(sql1, cn), _
                  da  As  New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

                da.Fill(dt)
            End Using

            Using cn  As New SqlConnection(conString2), _
                  cmd As New SqlCommand(sql2, cn)
           
                'Use actual types and lengths from the DB here!
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p0", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p5", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p6", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p7", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p8", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p9", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p10", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p11", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p12", SqlDbType.Int)

                cn.Open()
                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    For i As Integer = 0 To 12
                        cmd.Parameters($"@p{i}").Value = row(i)
                    Next i

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    FileIO.WriteLog($"Most Recent Normac ID {row(0)}")            
                Next row
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            FileIO.WriteLog(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I really appriciate your help, after running your code it gives me this error "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition." I believe that's because I have some extra columns in the destination table which is required for another purpose. How should I skip those unwanted columns and add only for the columns which I need?

Comment: I figured out the error, added DBNull.Value for the parameters that does not pass any value. Thank you very much sir for your help again :)

Comment: Or, like I advised in my answer, specify all the columns in your INSERT that you want to insert to: `INSERT INTO ALL_LABOR_DETAILS (ID, trx_date, work_order ...) VALUES (@p0,@p1,@p2...)` - see the column names after the ALL_LABOR_DETAILS..

Answer (score 2):

> I'm surprised with this error

You shouldn't be; every single one of the SQL Injection Hacking prone values you've concatenated into your INSERT statement, is a varchar, because theyre surrounded with `''`.

Don't just surround every value in any SQL you ever write, with `''`

```
--no
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age = '32'

--yes
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age = 32
```

As to your actual problem, you should properly parameterize your insert SQL and set the parameter types accurately. Do the setup of the command once:

```vb
cmd1 = New SqlCommand("Insert into ALL_LABOR_DETAILS (ID, trx_date, work_order ...) values(@p0, @p1, @p2 ...)")

cmd1.Parameters.Add("@p0", SqlDbType.Int)
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.DateTime) 'if it's a datetime2 with a scale, use the overload that accepts a SqlParameter, and do a New With to set the scale
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.VarChar)
...
```

Then inside the loop repeatedly set new values and Execute the command:

```vb
cmd1.Parameters("@p0").Value = dr(0) 'or whatever dr index you want ID to be
cmd1.Parameters("@p1").Value = dr(1) 'or whatever dr index you want trx_date to be
cmd1.Parameters("@p2").Value = dr(2) 'or whatever dr index you want work_order to be
...
```

Name all the columns you want to insert to, after the table name in your INSERT, that way you don't have to insert loads of dummy values

---

.. or perhaps consider using an SqlCommandBuilder to create the INSERT for you from the table definition